# Why do Ember view customEvents only pass one parameter?

Tags: ember.js

I am using the twitter typeahead lib, and it can send custom events. One such event is "typeahead:selected" which is documented to pass 3 parameters to the event handler.

To catch that event in Ember, I first do this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    customEvents: {
         "typeahead:selected": "onTypeaheadSelected"
    }
})
```

and in a view, I do this:

```
TypeaheadTextField: Ember.TextField.extend({
    onTypeaheadSelected: function(a,b,c) {
        console.log("onTypeaheadSelected", arguments, a, b, c);
    },
})
```

But only the first parameter has been set by ember, which is the jQuery event object. Params "b" and "c" are undefined.

If I instead try and listen directly on the events via jQuery using this code in my view:

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    this.$().typeahead().on('typeahead:selected', function(a,b,c) {
        console.log("onTypeaheadSelected", arguments, a, b, c);
    });
}
```

I am getting all of "a", "b" and "c" with values, so typeahead is actually sending them.

This is ember 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general implementation of event callbacks is to pass back `SomeCustomEvent` arg which contains all of the arguments for the event.  They programmed the customEvent handler around this concept (probably short-sighted, unless there is some document out there stating it's the law of the land).  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

That being said, you'll need to implement it at the view layer like you did.  You can create a mixin, or base class (which is essentially the same thing) so you don't need to recreate the code over and over.

```
App.TypeAheadView = Em.View.extend({
  setupTypeAhead: function () {
    this.$().typeahead().on('typeahead:selected', this.typeAhead);
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
  killTypeAhead: function(){
    this.$().typeahead().off('typeahead:selected', this.typeAhead);
  }.on('willDestroyElement'),
  typeAhead:function(a,b,c) {
    console.log("onTypeaheadSelected", arguments, a, b, c);
  }
});

App.BlahView = App.TypeAheadView.extend();

App.CowView =  App.TypeAheadView.extend();
```